# How to make a port of some linux command for Android OS?

Tags: android, linux

I'm looking for a way to use CDMA modem in my Android device.
Modem is recognized successfully, pppd is present however it lacks a 'chat' program.

Could anybody explain what steps are involved to port some linux program to Android ?
I want to know just basics, how to achieve this.
I saw that people create custom linux dists for Android, so I suppose I need to look in that direction.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Not to be very crude, but the first step would be 'open up an editor', followed by 'read source of chat program', followed by 'credit original author and insert proper license' and the rest should follow pretty smoothly from there

To be honest: android runs a linux kernel and uses a small libc (derived from BSD).

So you should probably be able to run the BSD chat cross-compiled for android as-is